# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool' using a random number generator and if statments

Tags: c#

Im trying to setup a random number generator, then have a `if` statement that has different outcomes depending on the number that comes out of the random number generator.

I've tried using `switch` statements for each number that comes out, I got a similar error about converting types.

```
public class Program
{
   public void Main(string[] toast)
   {
     Random number = new Random();
     int num01 = number.Next(1, 5);
     if (num01 = 1)
     {
       // something would go here
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`. One **assigns**. The other **compares**.

Comment: If (num01 == 1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case you problem in one =,but need == for compares.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] toast)
        {
            Random number = new Random();
            int num01 = number.Next(1, 5);
            if (num01 = 1) // error here, need ==
            {
                //something would go here
            }
        }
    }
```

but I'm seeing you going to use multiple numbers, so I offer you use switch case

```
switch(num01){
case 1:
  something;
  break;
case 2:
  something;
  break;
...other
}
```

Comment: @mjwills no problem, but i wanna show other way for questioner

Comment: They said: "I've tried using switch statements for each number that comes out, I got a similar error about converting types."

Comment: thank you, changing it to == worked. but again with the switch method. I did `switch (num01)
            {
                case "num01 == 1": 
            }` and got the error cannot implicitly convert type string to int (CS0029)

Comment: @matthewelsiray one more time look at the example.In switch case you not use ==, I've already showed you how it work, why you decided add "num01 == 1":.
"num01 == 1":  the same as  case 1:

Answer (score -2):

When using an `if` statement and checking if something is equal, you need to use `==` rather than `=`, as a single equal sign will act as an assignment. It may be better for you to do it explicitly, even though it may add more code, it may make things more clear to you or anyone reading over your code in the future. However, try the `==` first and see if that works.

Comment: I would add that if you do post an answer to a question like this, make it great. For example, explain the conversion error; what is exactly going on there? Also, what do you mean by "do it explicitly?" `if((num01 == 1) == true)`?